# Are sneer quotes the same exact thing as scare quotes?

Tags: word-choice, orthography

Are sneer quotes the same exact thing as scare quotes? I believe they're synonymous but am unsure.

Answer (score 3):

According to the extensive article at  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes), they're a subset:

> **Scare quotes** are quotation marks placed around a word or phrase to
>   imply that it may not signify its apparent meaning or that it is not
>   necessarily the way the quoting person would express its concept....
>
> *Negative*
>
> The effect of using scare quotes is often similar to prepending a
>   skeptical modifier such as so-called or alleged to label the quoted
>   word or phrase, to indicate scorn, sarcasm, or irony. Scare quotes may
>   be used to express disagreement with the original speaker's intended
>   meaning without actually establishing grounds for disagreement or
>   disdain, or without even explicitly acknowledging it. In this type of
>   usage, they are sometimes called "**sneer quotes**".
>
> Examples:
>
> Liberal: We've heard about these conservatives and their tax "relief".
>
> Conservative: The liberals have proposed yet another form of
>   "common-sense" gun control.